# Get --dart-define environment variables in native iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I am trying to find a way to access the environment variables provided by `--dart-define` inside native iOS and Android code.

Is there any way to do this?

I have tried the guide explained in https://binary-studio.com/2020/06/23/flutter-3/ but that doesn't work as what gets written to the generated `.xcconfig` is not separated by `=` but instead by `%3D`. And I get the error

```
error: .../ios/Flutter/DEFINEEnvironment.xcconfig:2: expected a ‘=’, but found % (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
```

The file `DEFINEEnvironment.xcconfig` gets generated with the following content `MY_VAR%3DMY_VALUE` instead of `MY_VAR=MY_VALUE`

**UPDATE**

This seems to be happening because when reading from the args passed to `--dart-define` it must be encoding `=` into `%3D`. And I don't know how prevent that from happening

Comment: Hi) sorry for this confusion) I've updated article on medium long time ago, and even published a new article regarding changes in 1.20) but for some reason article in our blog still wasn't updated (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the script has been changed and now includes the necessary code to decode the strings.

The post-action script that needs to be added to Scheme is:

```
function urldecode() { : "${*//+/ }"; echo "${_//%/\\x}"; }

IFS=',' read -r -a define_items <<< "$DART_DEFINES"


for index in "${!define_items[@]}"
do
    define_items[$index]=$(urldecode "${define_items[$index]}");
done

printf "%s\n" "${define_items[@]}" > ${SRCROOT}/Flutter/DEFINEEnvironment.xcconfig
```